# How to access other class members(ivars) in a class without making it public?

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, nsobject

I have wrote the following objective c class..

```
@interface thumb_user_info : NSObject
{
@public // Otherwise I was not able to access in other class.
    NSString *user_name;
    int       user_id;
}
@end
```

When I create instance in other class and try to set value for the user_id, it shows error "it is protected", how to access those ivars without making it public like above. I know its very basics in objective C, I don't want to hesitate to make myself clear.

NOTE: I have tried by synthesis it also... still same error...

thanks.

Comment: Did you add property for that objects ?

Comment: @MidhunMP Ya I tried, and synthesized in .mm, I was expected it will create a getter, but same error.

Comment: Remove "@public" . After the "}" add "@property NSString* user_name;" In the .m file write: "@synthesize user_name"; I see no reason why this won't work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The thing you are asking is one of the fundamental of OOP, Object Oriented Programming.

You encapsulate, bind, hide your private property from outside world by making it private.

If you want them visible you make it public.

If you wnat them to be hidden but inheritable you make it protected.

So, no way to access your private ivars/methods from outside self class.

If you want to access private ivars value, then make a public method and indirectly get/return the value.

**synthesize creates methods for the ivars (private/protected/public), if it is in .h it becomes public.**

Comment: Ya, but what is the use of synthesization there, it will generate  setter and getter for it right?

Comment: synthesize makes the methods public not the ivar.

Comment: instance_of_thumb->user_id = 5; // Will it invoke getter or not? // I have seen in one of example, they mentioned it will call getter if we did synthesis

Comment: @Newbee you should rarely or never use `->` in objective-c, you should access a property with `instance_of_thumb.user_id`. Accessing the ivars directly without getter/setter (`->`) is dangerous.

Comment: pointers can do any magic for you, Have you tried to mutate an NSString? you can, but you always say, no it "can not be"

Comment: @JonathanCichon Using (->) instead of setter/getter will the ivar thread safe?

Comment: @AKV I got confused with that example, but your point "synthesize makes the methods public not the ivar" makes it clear, Please mention the same in your answer, so that I can accept.

Comment: Updated something... differnt with full explanation

Comment: @sanjitshaw i dont think so

Answer (score 2):

It is instance var , not property , so you can not set value for them by `yourclass.user_name = userName` , I think you should better add some method to set the value such as :

```
- (void)setupUserName:(NSString *)userName
{
    user_name = userName
}
```